# node.js directory search for file with name

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need help writing a node.js application that searches for all sub directories under the current directory which their names contain the specified string.

for example the user want to search all directories that have the string 'test' in it.

what is the js code i need to use?

i try using this:

```
var walk = function(dir) {
var results = []
var list = fs.readdirSync(dir)
list.forEach(function(file) {
    file = dir + '/' + file
    var stat = fs.statSync(file)
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) results = results.concat(walk(file))
    else results.push(file)
})
return results
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)

In your case you could use it like this. This pattern will give you all files in the folder that contain at least once test in the name.

```
var glob = require("glob")

glob("+(test).js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
  if (er) {
      // omg something went wrong
      throw new Exception(er);
  }
  var requiredFiles = files.map(function(filename) {
      return require(filename);
  });
  // do something with the required files
});
```

Comment: what do i need to write inside the function ?

Comment: I edited an little example in it. I suppose you want to require that files and do something with it them